# Getting new column data for Telerik table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik-grid

I have taken over helping with development of a Visual Studio project written in C#, with me sadly not knowing much C# or the way these kind of projects work. Luckily I do have some experience in programming and can make sense of most of it.

However I now have a table with user data that I want to expand to include a column for the email address. I tried going to practically any file, but I can't find where the actual data is gotten from the database. I've commented out a "pro" column that isn't needed anymore, but the new "email" column shows the checkbox that was in the now removed "pro" column.

I've added the line to add the email column to the table and I've added a get, set for it in the .cs file. Can anyone point me in the direction to figure out where all this data is actually pulled from the database?

```cs
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<OnsPlatform.ViewModels.Admin_User>(Model.users)
    .Name("Grid_Users")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.userName).Title(Common.AdminUsers_Name);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Email).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "email" }).Title(Common.AdminUsers_email);
        columns.Bound(o => o.userID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(o => o.lastVisit).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy}").Title(Common.AdminUser_LastVisit);
        columns.Bound(o => o.nrPageViews).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "number" }).Title(Common.AdminUsers_NrPageViews);
        columns.Bound(o => o.nrComments).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "number" }).Title(Common.AdminUsers_NrComments);
        //columns.Bound(o => o.pro).Title(Common.AdminUsers_Pro);
        columns.Template(@<text>
            <a href="#" onclick="EditUser('@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["communityName"].ToString()',@item.userID);">@Common.Edit</a>
        </text>).Title(Common.Invitations_Action);
    })
    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(o => o.userID))
    .Selectable()
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowSelected("onRowSelected"))
    .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
    .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(true))
)
```

And I have added the following rule in `Admin_User.cs` (in the correct place):

```cs
public bool Email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got some help on Reddit, I had to right click the code and select "Go to controller", that sent me to a controller that led me to the eventual right controller where I could add an extra `adminUser.Email` variable.

Might be better to delete this question as I am very new to all this, but eh, you guys decide.